# Recursive Cypher query with prune condition

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher

I need to find all the nodes of a tree for which themselves and all their parents meet a specific condition (here they must have a *VISIBLE_BY* link to *John*).

[image: Scheme]

```
MATCH (start:Node)-[:PARENT_OF *0..]->(node:Node)-[:VISIBLE_BY]->(user:Person)
WHERE start.name = 'root' AND user.name = 'john'
RETURN node
```

This would return **[root, nodeA, nodeA1, nodeB1]** but **nodeB1** should actually be excluded...

Ideally, the prune condition should stop the exploration of a branch as soon as a node does not meet the specified condition as the tree could be much bigger and it would be a waste...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of this will very based on your Neo4J Cypher Version and DB setup, but this should be more efficient than blindly checking all paths. Basically, find the potential nodes, and then check if a viable path exists for each of them.

```
MATCH (root)-[:VISIBLE_BY]->(john) 
WHERE root.id = $root AND john.id = $john 
OPTIONAL MATCH (nodez)-[:VISIBLE_BY]->(john) 
WITH root, john, nodez, COLLECT(nodez) as viz
WHERE ANY(p IN (root)-[*..25]->(nodez) WHERE ALL (n IN NODES(p) WHERE n IN viz))
RETURN *
```

For even better performance at scale, you should look into the Neo4J [Traversal API](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal)

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH p=(u:Person { name: "john" })<-[:VISIBLE_BY|PARENT_OF*1..3]-(n)
WHERE (n)-[:VISIBLE_BY]-(u)
RETURN *
```

should meet your use requirements, also check out APOC's expand path algorithms!

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths

Comment: After correcting your query (VISIBLE_TO -> VISIBLE_BY), the query yelds no results (no changes, no records). What did you intend with [:VISIBLE_TO|PARENT_OF*2]?

Comment: Just amended the relationship name and taken out the label on the final node. Note also edited earlier to add the variable length of the relationship - try now!

Comment: Just to explain, that query will match anybn

Comment: ...match any node that's connected to John via one or two relationships with either of those labels!

Comment: It still however yelds no results... Be careful that the :VISIBLE_BY relation links a node to John and the PARENT_OF relation links nodes between themselves in order to make a tree.

Comment: Does it really return no nodes at all? Are the directions of your relationships definitely accurate in that image?

Comment: I've edited the query to make it even more general and match paths rather than nodes, try now? Hopefully thisbwill be close to what you need. You can then look to limit / order then by `size(nodes(p))`

Comment: It returns no node at all and yes the relations are like on the images. But i found out why: John vs john (sorry it took so long to spot it)... However the last request you make still returns nodeB1

Comment: Ah ha, that'll be it! Put the relationship back in now, should work!

Comment: Nop, here both nodeB and nodeB1 are included... nodeB should not be included as it does not have a VISIBLE_BY john relation and nodeB1 should not be returned either as its parent (but it could be its grandparent, grandgrandgrandparent, etc.) does not ha a VISIBLE_BY john relation...

Comment: Oh i see - try now!

Comment: I changed the RETURN to only return n... but your query does not eliminate nodeB1.

Comment: Ah sorry - maybe I wasn't fully understanding your requirement, you want to match all nodes visible to John, where all parent nodes are visible to John Also?

Comment: It's ok i finally found a solution... will post it shortly, thanks for your help. Once you've seen the solution, if you can find a more efficient way to do it, feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution:

```
MATCH (u:Person)<-[:VISIBLE_BY]-(n:Node),
      p = (n)<-[:PARENT_OF *1..]-(l:Node)
WHERE u.name = 'john' AND all(x in nodes(p) WHERE (x)-[:VISIBLE_BY]->(u))
RETURN nodes(p)
```

If there is a better (more efficient) or simpler solution, feel free to comment.

*(I hope there is a more efficient solution as this computes all pathes from any leaf/node of the tree to the root then filters out those with nodes that do not meet the condition... that will no scale well)*

Comment: You may want to profile this on a larger graph. You should see that the `all()` predicate should be truncating during expansion if the :VISIBLE_BY relationship doesn't exist, so it will cut off as soon as it reaches a node that isn't visible. However, maybe it's best to work from the root down rather than from visible nodes up.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try collecting the visible nodes first, and use membership in that visible nodes collection in your WHERE ALL.

This assumes that we'll always be starting from the root node:

```
with [(:Person{name:'John'})<-[:VISIBLE_BY]-(n) | n] as visible
match p=(:Node{name:'root'})-[:PARENT_OF*0..]->(n)
where all(m in nodes(p) where m in visible)
return n
```